# How to reuse a rim after the brake edge has been damaged

Tags: brakes, chain, fixed-gear, rims, brake-pads

My chain fell of and got stuck a few days ago (i ride fixed gear) and made a real mess of my back rim.

I noticed 2 marks on the brake edge of the rim where the chain scraped along.
they are not very deep (under 1mm) and 1-2cm long.

Is there any way i can make the rim brakable again, without having to change my brake pads once a week? Since the incident i haven't been using the back brake because of this...

Comment: I would just lightly sand the immediate area of the scratches so that no jagged edges project outward.  You'll get a little roughness and pad wear at first, until the spots wear down from braking action, but it shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the rim is thick enough still for safe braking, what I'd do is take the tire off the wheel and lightly sand/file the edges of the marks until they're level with the rest of the braking surface. I wouldn't sand/file until the marks are gone since that will likely give warbling and possibly remove too much of the surface. I'd recommend sanding in the direction of the brake travel.

There is also [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/18107/fixing-damage-to-brake-rim-surface) which the asker has outlined all the normal choices as well:

- "Leave it and let it smooth out with use. May take some time and wear down brake pads faster.
- Lightly sand the worst offending parts with high grit abrasive paper.
- Fill the damage with expoxy (or similar) then sand.
- Replace the rim (would it worth the labour cost?)"